# Floating PagerTabStrip

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using a `ViewPager` with a `PagerTabStrip` at the top. The background of the last is transparent so you can see what is behind it. But the `PagerTabStrip` shares the space assigned to the child views. What I want to do is set the `PagerTabStrip` as a floating view (like on `FrameLayout`s) so that the child views would expand behind the `PagerTabStrip`.

[image: see below image]

Answer (score -1):

Wrap your ViewPager in a FrameLayout and add your PagerTitleStrip to it with a layout_height of wrap_content and layout_gravity set to top|fill_horizontal. You might also want to set your paddingTop in your ViewPager to the height of your PagerTitleStrip. In which case you'll want to use a fixed height for the PagerTitleStrip.

Comment: The `PagerTitleStrip` must be a direct child of a `ViewPager`. If not the next exception is thrown: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: PagerTitleStrip must be a direct child of a ViewPager.`

Comment: And if you wrap the `ViewPager` with a `FrameLayout` everything remains as before, the `PagerTitleStrip` is a child of the `ViewPager`, not the `FrameLayout`, and `ViewPager` layout rules applies.